# Are C++11 stateful allocators interchangeable across type boundaries?

Tags: c++, c++11, allocator

My question here is basically a follow up to :

**[How can I write a stateful allocator in C++11, given requirements on copy construction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24278803/how-can-i-write-a-stateful-allocator-in-c11-given-requirements-on-copy-constr?rq=1)**

Basically, despite the fact that the C++11 standard now allows for stateful allocators, we still have the requirement that if you copy a certain `Allocator`, the copy must compare equal via the `==` operator with the original.  This indicates that the copy can safely *deallocate* memory which was allocated by the original, and vice-versa.

So, right off the bat this already prohibits an allocator from maintaining unique internal state, like a slab-allocator or memory pool or something.  One solution would be to use a `shared_ptr` pointer-to-implementation idiom for the internal state, so that all copies of some original `Allocator` use the same underlying memory pool.  That's not too bad.  Except...

According to the above referenced question, as well as the accepted answer, the standard *also* seems to require that `Allocator<T>` has an interoperable copy constructor with `Allocator<U>`, so that:

```
Allocator<T> alloc1;
Allocator<U> alloc2(alloc1);
assert(alloc1 == alloc2); // must hold true
```

So in other words, allocator types must be *interoperable* regardless of different template parameters.  That means if I allocate some memory using `Allocator<T>`, I must be able to deallocate that memory using an `Allocator<U>` instance constructed from the original `Allocator<T>`.

...and that's pretty much a show-stopper for any attempt to write an allocator that uses some sort of size-based memory pool, like a simple_segregated_storage pool that only returns chunks of a certain size based on `sizeof(T)`.

But... is this really true?

I realize the interoperable copy constructor is required for `Allocator<T>::rebind` so users of containers don't need to know the internal details of say, a linked-list node type or something.  But as far as I can see, the [**standard itself**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3376.pdf) doesn't seem to say anything so draconian as the requirement that an `Allocator<U>` constructed from an `Allocator<T>` must compare equal with the original `Allocator<T>` instance.

The standard basically requires the following semantics, where **X** is a type `Allocator<T>`, **a1** and **a2** are instances of **X**, **Y** is a type `Allocator<U>`, and **b** is an instance of `Allocator<U>`.

From: **§ 17.6.3.5** (Allocator requirements)

```
a1 == a2 returns true only if storage allocated from each can be deallocated via the other.

operator == shall be reflexive, symmetric, and transitive, and shall not exit via an exception.

a1 != a2 : same as !(a1 == a2)

a == b : same as a == Y::rebind<T>::other(b)

a != b : same as !(a == b)

X a1(a); Shall not exit via an exception. post: a1 == a

X a(b); Shall not exit via an exception. post: Y(a) == b, a == X(b)
```

So, the way I read this, instances of `Allocator<T>` constructed from `Allocator<U>` are *not* necessarily interchangeable.  The standard merely requires that `a == b` must be equivalent to `Y(a) == b`,  ***not*** that `a == b` must be *true*!

I think the requirement for the cross-type-boundary copy constructor makes this confusing.  But, the way I read this, if I have an `Allocator<T>`, it must have a copy constructor that takes an `Allocator<U>`, but that *doesn't* imply that:

```
Allocator<T> alloc1;
Allocator<U> alloc2(alloc1);
assert(alloc2 == alloc1);
```

In other words, the way I read this, the above assertion is allowed to fail.  But I'm not confident in my understanding here, because:

1. The [accepted answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24278803/how-can-i-write-a-stateful-allocator-in-c11-given-requirements-on-copy-constr) says otherwise, and the answerer is a guy with 108K reputation
2. The interaction between copy constructor requirements and equality requirements in the standard is a bit confusing, and I may be misunderstanding the verbiage.

So, I am I correct here?  (Incidentally, the implementation of [`boost::pool_allocator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/pool/doc/html/boost_pool/pool/interfaces.html) seems to imply I am correct, assuming the boost developer cares about standards compliance, since this allocator is not interchangeable accross type boundaries.)

Comment: "That means if I allocate some memory using Allocator<T>, I must be able to deallocate that memory using an Allocator<U> instance constructed from the original Allocator<T>."  I don't think it means that.  Read [Casey's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24289614/103167) that explains that you'd need to `rebind` the `Allocator<U>` back to `T` before deallocating objects of type `T`.

Comment: [allocator.requirements]/9 says "An allocator may constrain the types on which it can be instantiated" which implies that you can constrain it to `sizeof(T) == some_fixed_size`.

Comment: "In other words ... the above assertion is allowed to fail." This doesn't help too much because `X(Y(a))==a` must still hold. Which means any allocator created from `a` must carry the same state `a` carries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last line that you quote:

> `X a(b)`; Shall not exit via an exception. post: `Y(a) == b`, `a == X(b)`

Conflicts with your conclusion.

```
using X = Allocator<T>;
using Y = Allocator<U>;
Y b;
X a(b);
assert(Y(a) == b);
assert(a == X(b));
// therefore
assert(a == b);
```

Answer (score 2):

The standard does not entertain the possibility that objects (or values) of different types could ever be truly equal; this would contradict the very idea that objects have types. They can however *compare equal*, which just tells us what `operator==` would return when called for the objects. For different instances of an allocator template, it is specified that calling that operator between objects of those distinct types effectively replaces the second operand by an object of the type of the first operand but "copy-constructed" from the second operand, and then applies `operator==` for these equal type operands. (It escapes me why the type is specified as `Y::rebind<T>::other` (which need not be defined) rather than `allocator_traits<Y>::rebind_alloc<T>`, or better even simply `X`, the type of `a`; probably just an historic remnant.) So in the end, the comparison is always between objects of the same type; for that case (only) it is specified that equality means interoperability, i.e., that storage given out by one allocator can be recycled using the other.

So Yes, after saying `Y b(a)` where the type `X` of `a` is `Allocator<T>` while `Y` is `Allocator<U>`, it is ensured that `b == a`, which equals `b == Y(a)`, returns `true`; also `a == b`, which equals `a == X(b)` must return `true` (the passage you cited says so explicitly, though with some interchanges of names). But No, this does not mean that "if I allocate some memory using `Allocator<T>`, I must be able to deallocate that memory using an `Allocator<U>`", because that requirement is only made for equality of allocators of the same type. Indeed, it is not clear how one would even set up for such a deallocation, because the method `Allocator<U>::deallocate` has a first argument of type `Allocator<U>::pointer`, which is presumably `U*` and in any case different from `Allocator<T>::pointer`, so one could only get into this scenario after doing pointer type travesty, which I believe gives you Undefined Behaviour on the spot.

There is one implication, sort of, of the requirements that I would like to point out: an allocator type `Allocator<T>` can hardly have any non-`static` data members whose type depends on `T`. (With "hardly" I mean it is not rigorously impossible, just not doable in any useful manner.) Because if such a member accesses some storage resource useful for future allocations of type `T` (think of a pointer to `T` to some free space) with presumably equality of allocators requiring this resource to be shared (since allocations from one can be deallocated to another) then copy-constructing an `Allocator<U>` must somehow initialise the corresponding data member, which has a different type, and which can now be used as a resource or future allocations of type `U`, but still retain the identity of the resource (so it cannot simply construct an empty resource for type `U`) because copy-constructing back to `Allocator<T>` must result in the resource being shared with the original allocator; this I think is a very tall order.

My conclusion would be that in practice allocators have to be either stateless (no non-static data members at all) or else have a type-ignorant resource management (with in particular all data members independent of the `value_type`, and with all copy-constructed versions for different types of the same allocator sharing resources, just like `malloc` serves all types at once). Or both, like for `std::allocator`. But I'd love to be proven wrong.