# std::list in a boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory

Tags: c++, boost, stl, allocator, boost-interprocess

Recently I [got schooled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49738871/4288486) and learnt the proper way of having a `unordered_map` inside a `boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory` segment. So far so good, but I will need to add a few more STL containers.

Ideally, I would want to be able to follow the same for any STL container. Right now I'm in need of a [`std::list`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/). I can't make it work. I can make a [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) work, though.

### std::vector

The following code works:

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>

namespace ipc = boost::interprocess;
using Segment = ipc::managed_shared_memory;
using Manager = Segment::segment_manager;
template <typename T> using Alloc = ipc::allocator<T, Manager>;
template <typename K> using Vector = std::vector<K, Alloc<K>>;

int main() {
  boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object::remove("test");
  Segment _segment{ipc::create_only, "test", 1ul<<40};
  Manager *mgr = _segment.get_segment_manager();
  Vector<int> *v = _segment.construct<Vector<int>>("v")(mgr);
  v->emplace_back(1);
}
```

### std::list

The list-equivalent code results in an error.

```
#include <list>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>

namespace ipc = boost::interprocess;
using Segment = ipc::managed_shared_memory;
using Manager = Segment::segment_manager;
template <typename T> using Alloc = ipc::allocator<T, Manager>;
template <typename K> using List = std::list<K, Alloc<K>>;

int main() {
  boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object::remove("test");
  Segment _segment{ipc::create_only, "test", 1ul<<40};
  Manager *mgr = _segment.get_segment_manager();
  List<int> *v = _segment.construct<List<int>>("v")(mgr);
  v->emplace_back(1);
}
```

The compilation flags (using g++-7) and error are the following:

```
$ g++ -std=gnu++17 lol_list.cpp -lrt -pthread -rdynamic -Wfatal-errors && ./a.out && rm ./a.out
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/list:63:0,
                 from lol_list.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_list.h: In instantiation of ‘std::__cxx11::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Node* std::__cxx11::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_create_node(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {int}; _Tp = int; _Alloc = boost::interprocess::allocator<int, boost::interprocess::segment_manager<char, boost::interprocess::rbtree_best_fit<boost::interprocess::mutex_family>, boost::interprocess::iset_index> >; std::__cxx11::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Node = std::_List_node<int>]’:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_list.h:1801:32:   required from ‘void std::__cxx11::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_insert(std::__cxx11::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = {int}; _Tp = int; _Alloc = boost::interprocess::allocator<int, boost::interprocess::segment_manager<char, boost::interprocess::rbtree_best_fit<boost::interprocess::mutex_family>, boost::interprocess::iset_index> >; std::__cxx11::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_List_iterator<int>]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_list.h:1133:4:   required from ‘std::__cxx11::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::reference std::__cxx11::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::emplace_back(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {int}; _Tp = int; _Alloc = boost::interprocess::allocator<int, boost::interprocess::segment_manager<char, boost::interprocess::rbtree_best_fit<boost::interprocess::mutex_family>, boost::interprocess::iset_index> >; std::__cxx11::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::reference = int&]’
lol_list.cpp:16:20:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_list.h:578:11: error: cannot convert ‘boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<std::_List_node<int>, long int, long unsigned int, 0>’ to ‘std::__cxx11::list<int, boost::interprocess::allocator<int, boost::interprocess::segment_manager<char, boost::interprocess::rbtree_best_fit<boost::interprocess::mutex_family>, boost::interprocess::iset_index> > >::_Node* {aka std::_List_node<int>*}’ in return
    return __p;
           ^~~
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

The error persists with `g++-6` or `g++-8` and even with `clang-6.0` and `clang-5.0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all standard library implementations fully support stateful allocators (yet?).

In this case it appears that your `std::list<>` doesn't. Simply opt for the one for Boost Container, which is conveniently also available through Boost Interprocess headers:

```
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/list.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>

namespace ipc = boost::interprocess;
using Segment = ipc::managed_shared_memory;
using Manager = Segment::segment_manager;
template <typename T> using Alloc = ipc::allocator<T, Manager>;
template <typename K> using List = ipc::list<K, Alloc<K>>;

int main() {
    boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object::remove("test");
    Segment _segment{ipc::create_only, "test", 1ul<<40};
    Manager *mgr = _segment.get_segment_manager();
    List<int> *v = _segment.construct<List<int>>("v")(mgr);
    v->emplace_back(1);
}
```

Comment: This is a bit ironic, as per yesterday's comments on your `std::unordered_map` answer. This solution works -- compiles and inserts properly.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for posting the other self-answered question, upvoted that just now :)

Comment: Thanks for solving it :-D

Comment: Just wondering if this is is worthy of a bug report in `libstdc++`, as they claim to support stateful allocators...?

Comment: Do they claim it across the board? If they claim it for one container but not the other, it's not a bug. Perhaps there is a "feature readiness" page that makes the promises more explicit. Is not that plausible that they'd skip the feature "untested"

Comment: By the way, another frequent hurdle is the use of non-raw pointer types (so when `allocator <T>::pointer_type != T*`)

Comment: As the comment above this one says, the problem is not lack of support for stateful allocators, it's lack of support for "fancy pointers" and there's already a bug report: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57272

Answer (score 1):

> [[allocator.requirements]](http://eel.is/c++draft/allocator.requirements) paragraph 9:
>
> > An allocator may constrain the types on which it can be instantiated and the arguments for which its construct member may be called. If a type cannot be used with a particular allocator, the allocator class or the call to construct may fail to instantiate.
>
> It's OK for your allocator to refuse to allocate memory for anything except a T. That will prevent it being used in node-based containers such as std::list which need to allocate their own internal node types (not just the container's value_type) but it will work fine for std::vector

As posted in https://stackoverflow.com/a/28995278/4288486 by @Jonathan-Wakely

Comment: That's not the problem here though.