# Do rebound allocators get copied/moved when an allocator aware container gets copied/moved?

Tags: c++, c++11, allocator

This question is more of a curiosity than a practical question.

In C++, many containers are "noded based". Meaning that for storage, they can't **really** use the allocator passed to them, instead, they do something like:

```
typedef typename A::template rebind<node>::other node_allocator_type
```

and presumably creates a member of this type like this or similar:

```
node_allocator_type node_allocator;
```

To create an allocator that can allocate nodes. Great, this all makes sense, but I have a question about what happens during a copy/move of the container if the container is truly "allocator aware", supporting stateful allocators.

Does the node allocator get copied/moved too? That makes sense on a surface level, but what happens when we hit a copy/move-constructor where the user can specify a new allocator like these?

```
list( const list& other, const Allocator& alloc );
list( list&& other, const Allocator& alloc );
```

In this case, the `other`'s allocator isn't copied or moved, so does the newly constructed list get a brand new `node_allocator` along with it's copied/moved `alloc`?

This is obviously an implementation detail, but I'm curious about what is "right" and what typical implementations do. I also recognize that pre-C++11, stateful allocators weren't terribly well supported, and thus this was a non-issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumption is that copy-constructing allocators (even stateful allocators) is a cheap operation; if they have any associated resources they [should be held by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21975695/copy-stateful-allocator-standard-library-allocator-semantics-and-internal-memor?rq=1). Furthermore rebound allocators may be constructed by copy, and these compare equal to the original allocator; see `a == b` in [*Cpp17Allocator* requirements](http://eel.is/c++draft/allocator.requirements#tab:cpp17.allocator).

The upshot of this is that the container is entirely at liberty to store an `Allocator`, an `Allocator::rebind<void>`, or an `Allocator::rebind<node_type>`, and to copy-convert between them as necessary when allocating nodes, on move construction, on (prvalue!) return from `get_allocator()`, etc. Generally libstdc++ [stores](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/43c7ee54a2c49b8c153f1a072d87574be0de72a4/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/forward_list.h#L296) an `Allocator::rebind<node_type>`, for example.